# Why does JavaScript acts different with Sync/Async in React and node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, async-await

This is code from my React project.

If you read the onSearchSubmit `function written(line: 3) + "unsplash" is axios.create()` call

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = { images: [] };

    onSearchSubmit = async term => {
        const response = await unsplash.get('/search/photos', {
            params: { query: term }
        });
        this.setState({ images: response.data.results });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='ui container' style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
                <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
                <ImageList images={this.state.images} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If I hadn't used async, I would get an error message because a response variable is undefined(yet, due to time-consuming HTTP request)

***Therefore, the code
"doesn't wait"
for something to finish, rather it moves on with an undefined variable in React***

But in node js it's different.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const input = fs.readFileSync('input.txt', 'utf-8');
console.log(input);
```

This is a simple code which
***"waits"***
for the second line, and when it's over, the next line executes.

**What's the difference? Those two are both JS codes but acts differently for me.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `unsplash.get` returns a Promise

It returns a promise which needs to be resolved. As long it's not being resolved, it returns nothing, therefore response will be `undefined`. To resolve the Promise you can either use `await` inside an `async` function, like you did, to tell the code to `wait for` a result:

```js
const response = await unsplash.get();
```

or you can use classic `.then`

```js
unsplash.get()
.then((response) => {
  // ... continue here
})
.catch((error) => {
  // ... error handler
});
```

#### `readFileSync()` is a synchronous operation, does not return a Promise

As this is a normal synchronous function, your code only continues once this function is finished, by default.

Answer (score 0):

The axios `.get()` function is asynchronous so you must use `await` in order to have the `response` variable available, while `fs.readFileSync()` is a syncronous function (it's right in the name, the asyncrhonous version is `fs.readFile()`) so the code waits for it to complete.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this section](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_synchronous_example), it cited that

> The synchronous form blocks the Node.js event loop and further JavaScript execution until the operation is complete

So `readFileSync()` is a synchronous method that would wait for the operation to finish before moving on another operation. Even in its [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) shows that

> Returns: string | Buffer

FYI, `readFile` also has a [version that return promise](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options)